# I want to make two tables nested objects in Laravel controller

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I have two tables. One is the ability table and the other is the user table. I want to output these tables in a similar way to the following.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "fullName": "John Doe",
  "username": "johndoe",
  "avatar": "/img/13-small.d796bffd.png",
  "email": "admin@demo.com",
  "ability": [
    {
      "action": "manage",
      "subject": "all"
    }
  ],

}
```

But I get these

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Admin",
        "email": "admin@admin.com",
        "role": "Admin",
        "telefon": "05355141450",
        "password": "$2y$10$bigkDO75WWzeBCk60ZT/3eUvXlOKRocpYzWoTlhFhbSuft1ojdWDW",
        "status": "1"
    }
]
```

and

```
{
    "ability": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "action": "manage",
            "user_id": "1",
            "subject": "all"
        }
    ]
}
```

I use Laravel as framework. I'm pulling data with Query. But I couldn't do these two together. Can you please help?

Comment: Have you defined your relationships between a `User` and `Ability`? If not, you need to do so and then you can reference then when doing a transformation.

Comment: yeah I did. I pull like these     $a=DB::table('users')->where('id', '1')->get();
        $b=DB::table('ability')->where('user_id', '1')->get();

Comment: I mean [relationships on your models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Comment: I dont use models.